# Unexecuted user action code in Istanbul Code Coverage

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

I have Jasmine tests for a data service that does CRUD operations. There are some functions that are **only executed on user actions** like add, update or delete data. These functions are marked red by Istanbul which decreases the code coverage.

How should I handle these functions?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- exercise the user actions
  manually using a hand-written script so you can reliably repeat it,
- add a programmable way for your application to trigger these actions, and then
  write unit tests that use the triggers

I much prefer the latter because you can then simply run the tests whenever needed.